# Docker WordPress install via Composer Connection Timeout

Tags: linux, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

Im trying to install wordpress using Docker via composer for some reason. And here is my Dockerfile for that:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm-bullseye

RUN pecl install xdebug-3.2.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
# RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

# Install zip
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

COPY ./docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY ./docker/php/xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
COPY ./docker/php/error-logging.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error-logging.ini

WORKDIR /var/www
COPY ../../app /var/www

# Install WP CLI
RUN curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
RUN chmod +x wp-cli.phar
RUN mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp
RUN wp --info

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

# Install composer
# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer update
# RUN composer install -n --prefer-dist

# COPY ./docker/php/docker-bootup.sh /var/app/docker-bootup.sh
# CMD ["sh", "/var/app/docker-bootup.sh"]
```

and here is my `composer.json` :

```
{
    "require": {
        "johnpbloch/wordpress": "*",
        "wpackagist-theme/bold-photography":"1.3.2"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "wp-content/plugins/{$name}/": [
                "type:wordpress-plugin"
            ],
            "wp-content/themes/{$name}/": [
                "type:wordpress-theme"
            ]
        },
        "wordpress-install-dir": "wp"
    },
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://wpackagist.org"
    }],
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer": false
        }
    }
}
```

everything works fine from my other Dockerfile (apache and mysql) but when it comes to installing wordpress via composer it stopped and error shows as connection timeout.

Here is the log while doing `docker compose up -d` :

```
[+] Building 97.8s (19/19) FINISHED                                       docker:default
 => [php internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                            0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.39kB                                              0.0s 
 => [php internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8.2-fpm-bullseye         0.4s 
 => [php internal] load .dockerignore                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                     0.0s 
 => [php  1/15] FROM docker.io/library/php:8.2-fpm-bullseye@sha256:90ce145889273a6  0.0s 
 => [php internal] load build context                                               0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 1.26kB                                                 0.0s 
 => CACHED [php  2/15] RUN pecl install xdebug-3.2.0     && docker-php-ext-enable   0.0s 
 => CACHED [php  3/15] RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql              0.0s 
 => CACHED [php  4/15] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y     libzip-dev  0.0s 
 => CACHED [php  5/15] COPY ./docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini         0.0s 
 => CACHED [php  6/15] COPY ./docker/php/xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/dock  0.0s 
 => CACHED [php  7/15] COPY ./docker/php/error-logging.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf  0.0s 
 => CACHED [php  8/15] WORKDIR /var/www                                             0.0s 
 => [php  9/15] COPY ../../app /var/www                                             0.1s 
 => [php 10/15] RUN curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pag  1.1s
 => [php 11/15] RUN chmod +x wp-cli.phar                                            0.7s
 => [php 12/15] RUN mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp                                0.6s
 => [php 13/15] RUN wp --info                                                       0.7s
 => [php 14/15] RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-  1.5s
 => ERROR [php 15/15] RUN composer update                                          92.4s
------
 > [php 15/15] RUN composer update:
0.639 
0.639 Warning: Module "zip" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
0.681 
0.681 Warning: Module "zip" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
0.794 Loading composer repositories with package information
21.33 Updating dependencies
21.91 Lock file operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
21.91   - Locking composer/installers (v2.2.0)
21.91   - Locking johnpbloch/wordpress (6.4.3)
21.91   - Locking johnpbloch/wordpress-core (6.4.3)
21.91   - Locking johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer (2.0.0)
21.91   - Locking wpackagist-theme/bold-photography (1.3.2)
21.91 Writing lock file
21.91 Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
21.91 Package operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
21.91 As there is no 'unzip' nor '7z' command installed zip files are being unpacked using the PHP zip extension.
21.91 This may cause invalid reports of corrupted archives. Besides, any UNIX permissions (e.g. executable) defined in the archives will be lost.
21.91 Installing 'unzip' or '7z' (21.01+) may remediate them.
21.91   - Downloading johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer (2.0.0)
21.91   - Downloading composer/installers (v2.2.0)
21.92   - Downloading johnpbloch/wordpress-core (6.4.3)
21.92   - Downloading johnpbloch/wordpress (6.4.3)
21.92   - Downloading wpackagist-theme/bold-photography (1.3.2)
21.93  0/5 [>---------------------------]   0%A connection timeout was encountered. If you intend to run Composer without connecting to the internet, run the command again prefixed with COMPOSER_DISABLE_NETWORK=1 to make Composer run in offline mode.
37.44   - Downloading johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer (2.0.0)
37.94   - Downloading composer/installers (v2.2.0)
38.44   - Downloading johnpbloch/wordpress-core (6.4.3)
38.94   - Downloading johnpbloch/wordpress (6.4.3)
39.44   - Downloading wpackagist-theme/bold-photography (1.3.2)
54.45   - Downloading johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer (2.0.0)
54.95   - Downloading composer/installers (v2.2.0)
55.45   - Downloading johnpbloch/wordpress-core (6.4.3)
55.96   - Downloading johnpbloch/wordpress (6.4.3)
56.46   - Downloading wpackagist-theme/bold-photography (1.3.2)
71.47   - Downloading johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer (2.0.0)
71.97   - Downloading composer/installers (v2.2.0)
72.47   - Downloading johnpbloch/wordpress-core (6.4.3)
72.97   - Downloading johnpbloch/wordpress (6.4.3)
73.47   - Downloading wpackagist-theme/bold-photography (1.3.2)
77.87
77.87  1/5 [=====>----------------------]  20%    Failed to download johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer from dist: curl error 28 while downloading https://codeload.github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer/legacy.zip/237faae9a60a4a2e1d45dce1a5836ffa616de63e: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
92.25     Now trying to download from source
92.25
92.25  2/5 [===========>----------------]  40%    Failed to download composer/installers from dist: curl error 28 while downloading https://codeload.github.com/composer/installers/legacy.zip/c29dc4b93137acb82734f672c37e029dfbd95b35: Resolving timed out after 15001 milliseconds
92.30     Now trying to download from source
92.30     Failed to download johnpbloch/wordpress from dist: curl error 28 while downloading https://codeload.github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress/legacy.zip/b20c2071f4cd609953dbd7ffc97e5201094499f0: Resolving timed out after 14962 milliseconds
92.30     Now trying to download from source
92.31     Failed to download johnpbloch/wordpress-core from dist: curl error 28 while downloading https://codeload.github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress-core/legacy.zip/12iD3XhCQfYF5sf6FaMrzrGFxzrKJ4u85L: Resolving timed out after 14960 milliseconds
92.31     Now trying to download from source
92.31
92.31  5/5 [============================] 100%
92.31 In GitDownloader.php line 82:
92.31
92.31   git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download
92.31
92.31
92.31 update [--with WITH] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--no-autoloader] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [-w|--with-dependencies] [-W|--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-m|--minimal-changes] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>...]
92.31
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c composer update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by stripping your `Dockerfile` down to the minimal components required to demonstrate the problem.

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm-bullseye

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y -qq unzip

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

COPY composer.json .

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
    php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
# Allow the composer/installers plugin.
RUN composer config allow-plugins.composer/installers true
RUN composer update
```

I needed to do two things to get this to work:

- install `unzip` and
- allow the `composer/installers plugin` plugin.

[image]

Comment: just wierd it didnt create any folder called `wp` from the composer.json : https://i.postimg.cc/XvMKy7dM/image.png

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/7Z40xQkD/image.png

Comment: I don't really know enough about `composer` to be sure. Why were you expecting a `wp` folder? Is that where you were expecting the `johnpbloch` content to be installed? I see that those have been installed into the `/var/www/html/vendor` directory.

Comment: I'm glad that this worked though. If you're happy with the answer, please go ahead and accept it.